# List Calendars available for user on CalDAV (Bedework)

Tags: .net, caldav, ipworks

I use IP*Works .Net CalDAV-component* to operate on a Bedework quickstart calendar server, set up on localhost:8080. In order to access calendars I need to know their resource URI.

When using Baikal (SabreDAV) as the server, I simply used WebDAV ListDirectory to see subdirectories, which would be the various calendar URIs.

However, I can't make this work on Bedework, it only returns the base-URL.

'http://localhost:8080/ucaldav/principals/users/vbede/'

What is the appropriate way to get calendars for a user on CalDAV? 
And more specifically on Bedework?

- http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/
- https://wiki.jasig.org/display/BWK38/The+Bedework+Quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bedework and SabreDAV uses different authentication schemes. Use the default BasicAuth with Bedework, and Digest with SabreDAV.

Also, limit WebDav.Depth to immediate children, and use:

```
http://localhost:8080/ucaldav/user/#{username}/
```